# What does the value 254 mean on this map?

Tags: mapping, land-surface

NASA has a land cover map that tells you what type of biome is on the Earth's surface:

[here](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/61004/new-land-cover-classification-maps)

There are 17 different land types. If you download one of the two tiffs here and zoom into a couple of places you'll see that some pixels are black. This ends up being a value of 254, whereas all the other values are 0 to 16, for the 17 different values. But the black pixels you see there have the value of 254. Would you happen to know what these are? And where would I be able to find out?

Comment: Err, which map of all those? If it's the value for black and black is not in the legend then it is probably just a placeholder value.

Comment: I agree that it is very likely that this value means something like "no data" or "undefined".

Comment: given that the largest number possible in 8-bit hexadecimal is 255 it is almost certainly some type of coding error.

Comment: @John Do you know where I can get a high detail land cover map like that in high res, a better one? I found this: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/mcd12c1v061/ but the tiles don't even seem to be arranged in any comprehensible way.

Comment: no idea, sorry, I don't use nasa for much